# How to insert an image from file into a PlotWidget (plt1 = pg.PlotWidget(w);)?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqtgraph

How to insert an image from file into a PlotWidget `(plt1 = pg.PlotWidget(w);)`?
The image is for a layout on which some calculated and plotted points should appear.

I tried to insert the image in a Qlabel behind the PlotWidget and make the PlotWidget transparent, but didn't work as transparency takes the color of the window not real transparency.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use QGraphicsPixmapItem:

```
plt1 = pg.PlotWidget(w)
img = pg.QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem(pg.QtGui.QPixmap(fileName))
plt1.addItem(img)

# depending on your preference, you probably want to invert the image:
img.scale(1, -1)

# OR invert the entire view:
plt.invertY(True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. But the image is greatly over-scaled (zoomed-in). The way that the graph shows only about 1/8 of the image. So how can I fit the image in the graph size , or better, within certain range in x and y of the graph?
Thanks

Comment: Use QGraphicsItem.scale, translate, setTransform, etc. It would be very useful  to familiarize yourself with QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsItem, and the various subclasses provided by Qt.